# Strings & Linked Lists - C Programming

Tags: c

I currently have the code:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head,*var,*trav;

void insert_at_end(int value)
{
      struct node *temp; 
      temp=head;
      var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
      var->data=value;
      if(head==NULL)
      {
          head=var;
          head->next=NULL;
      }
      else
      {
          while(temp->next!=NULL)
          {     
               temp=temp->next;
          }
          var->next=NULL;
          temp->next=var;
      }
}

void display()
{
     trav=head;
     if(trav==NULL)
     {
          printf("\nList is Empty");
     }
     else
     {
          printf("\nElements in the List: ");
          while(trav!=NULL)
          {
               printf(" -> %d ",trav->data);
               trav=trav->next;
          }
      printf("\n");
      }
}

int main(){

  int value;
  scanf("%d", &value);
  insert_at_end(value);
  display();
  return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine for inserting a int. But, I want to insert an string. A word like "Dog". I changed

```
int data to char data[255];
```

And changed all the instances of "%d" to "%s", but this doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should provide the code that you believe should do whatever you want.

Comment: You'd have to `strcpy` your data instead of assigning. Direct assignment doesn't work with arrays.

Comment: How do you update `var->data=value;` ?  Don't cast malloc

Comment: You should change the `int` field to `char*` and `malloc()` enough memory for `strlen()+1`, then copy the string. BTW using global vars is a cheap but poor way of handling it all.

Comment: So, insert_at_end(strcpy(value))?

Comment: No, `strcpy(var->data, value)` inside `insert_at_end()`. But beware of buffer overruns.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Show the code that does not work! Code that works is ok as reference, but it is kinda pointless to show some code, and ask about different code...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the following changes:

1. "int data" into "char data[255]"
2. Change the argument of insert_at_end to "char *value"
3. The following lines instead of the assignment into insert_at_end:

   strncpy(var->data, value, sizeof(var->data));

   var->data[sizeof(var->data)-1] = '\0';
4. Change %d into %s
5. Change the code that reads the value from input into the following:

   char value[255];

   fgets(value, sizeof(value), stdin);

   insert_at_end(value);

This code doesn't strip the newline that fgets will read. It is left as an exercise to the reader how to strip the extra newline. It is also left as an exercise to the reader how to allocate memory dynamically so that variable-length strings can be supported (hint: use malloc and remember to free it!)

However, to understand why these changes need to be made and to understand how arrays, strings and pointers work in C I recommend reading a basic C book. The full explanation doesn't fit into this limited answer. I see from your question that you fail to understand some basic principles of C, and it may be the case C is not necessarily the best language for you to use now.

I also recommend reading some basic secure coding guidelines to understand why the '\0' assignment is done after strncpy as strncpy is an inherently unsafe function.